# Oracle Apex 19.1 PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'AJAX'

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-ords

After install Oracle Apex 19.1, it give me error PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'AJAX'.

While others requests works well, ajax calls does not.

- Database Versión : Oracle XE 18c
- Ords Versión: ords-18.4.0.354.1002
- Apex Versión: apex_19.1

Example: 
While exporting interactive reports, on action menu do i get:

```
Error Message
1 error has occurred
Error: Internal Server Error
```

Below is the request debug information.

```
500 Internal Server Error
Debug Trace
mapped request using: /*:PL/SQL to: |apex||
Choosing: oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex as current candidate with score: PLSQLDispatchScore
==== Processing Request: ====
--Attributes--
oracle.dbtools.http.ecid = 1JGSqZb04VdZow0hkAUABA..
ECID-Principal = ECIDPrincipal [ecid=1JGSqZb04VdZow0hkAUABA..]
oracle.dbtools.common.di.Services = URL Mapped Scope
oracle.dbtools.plugin.api.di.InstanceLocator = oracle.dbtools.common.di.Services$InstanceLocator@790e130f
oracle.dbtools.http.servlet.dispatch.score = PLSQLDispatchScore
--Attributes--
GET /apps/wwv_flow.ajax HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.zeubot.com
host: dev.zeubot.com
connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3745.4 Safari/537.36
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es-US;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,es-419;q=0.6
cookie: ORA_WWV_REMEMBER_UN=; ORA_WWV_REMEMBER_LANG=e_; COM.ZEUBOT.APPS=OR__3j; ORA_WWV_USER_248216610599740=OR__uP; ORA_WWV_USER_250144942747276=OR__ma
content-length: 0


org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@7071c536
Using Procedure:wwv_flow.ajax
SID: 60
PATCHING: APPLIED
isValidRequest(), procedure name: <wwv_flow.ajax>
Validating: wwv_flow.ajax
*** Total number of arguments: 61
Checking procedure <wwv_flow.ajax>  exclude= false
Parse: 0 ms
-----
begin 
 wwv_flow.ajax;
commit;
  end;
*** Total number of arguments: 61

#### Error occurred in Signature for procedure: wwv_flow.ajax. Reloading...
*** Total number of arguments: 61
*** Total number of arguments: 61

EXEC FAILED:ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'AJAX'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'AJAX'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1052)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:537)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:610)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:249)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:82)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:924)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1136)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3640)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeInternal(T4CCallableStatement.java:1318)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3752)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4242)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1079)
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.oracle$1ucp$1jdbc$1proxy$1StatementProxy$2oracle$1jdbc$1internal$1OracleCallableStatement$$$Proxy.execute(Unknown Source)
  at oracle.dbtools.apex.OWA.execute(OWA.java:184)
  at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.handleRequest(ModApex.java:299)
  at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.doGet(ModApex.java:143)
  at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.service(ModApex.java:107)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:143)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPoint$FilteredServlet.service(EntryPoint.java:243)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:73)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.forwarding.QueryFilteringRewrite.doFilter(QueryFilteringRewrite.java:90)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.forwarding.ForwardingFilter.doFilter(ForwardingFilter.java:68)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.cors.CORSPreflightFilter.doFilter(CORSPreflightFilter.java:66)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.cookies.auth.CookieSessionCSRFFilter.doFilter(CookieSessionCSRFFilter.java:75)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.AuthenticationFilter.authenticate(AuthenticationFilter.java:101)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.RequestMapperImpl.doFilter(RequestMapperImpl.java:161)
  at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.URLMappingBase.doFilter(URLMappingBase.java:95)
  at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.filter.URLMappingFilter.doFilter(URLMappingFilter.java:130)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.external.ExternalSessionFilter.doFilter(ExternalSessionFilter.java:59)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.rt.authentication.apex.ApexSessionQueryRewriteFilter.doFilter(ApexSessionQueryRewriteFilter.java:58)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.cors.CORSResponseFilter.doFilter(CORSResponseFilter.java:83)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpResponseFilter.doFilter(HttpResponseFilter.java:45)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.AbsoluteLocationFilter.doFilter(AbsoluteLocationFilter.java:65)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpResponseFilter.doFilter(HttpResponseFilter.java:45)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:85)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.secure.ForceHttpsFilter.doFilter(ForceHttpsFilter.java:74)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.ForceAuthFilter.doFilter(ForceAuthFilter.java:44)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.Filters.filter(Filters.java:67)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPoint.service(EntryPoint.java:82)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPointServlet.service(EntryPointServlet.java:102)
  at oracle.dbtools.entrypoint.WebApplicationRequestEntryPoint.service(WebApplicationRequestEntryPoint.java:50)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
  at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:394)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: Error : 6550, Position : 8, Sql = begin 
 wwv_flow.ajax;
commit;
  end;, OriginalSql = begin 
 wwv_flow.ajax;
commit;
  end;, Error Msg = ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'AJAX'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
  ... 91 more
==== Request Processed ====
[TE] GET /apps/wwv_flow.ajax start: 2019-03-31T16:21:43.558Z duration: 157ms


Stack Trace
InternalServerException [statusCode=500, reasons=[]]
  at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApexContext.handleError(ModApexContext.java:283)
  at oracle.dbtools.apex.OWA.execute(OWA.java:203)
  at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.handleRequest(ModApex.java:299)
  at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.doGet(ModApex.java:143)
  at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.service(ModApex.java:107)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:143)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPoint$FilteredServlet.service(EntryPoint.java:243)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:73)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.forwarding.QueryFilteringRewrite.doFilter(QueryFilteringRewrite.java:90)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.forwarding.ForwardingFilter.doFilter(ForwardingFilter.java:68)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.cors.CORSPreflightFilter.doFilter(CORSPreflightFilter.java:66)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.cookies.auth.CookieSessionCSRFFilter.doFilter(CookieSessionCSRFFilter.java:75)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.AuthenticationFilter.authenticate(AuthenticationFilter.java:101)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.RequestMapperImpl.doFilter(RequestMapperImpl.java:161)
  at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.URLMappingBase.doFilter(URLMappingBase.java:95)
  at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.filter.URLMappingFilter.doFilter(URLMappingFilter.java:130)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.external.ExternalSessionFilter.doFilter(ExternalSessionFilter.java:59)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.rt.authentication.apex.ApexSessionQueryRewriteFilter.doFilter(ApexSessionQueryRewriteFilter.java:58)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.cors.CORSResponseFilter.doFilter(CORSResponseFilter.java:83)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpResponseFilter.doFilter(HttpResponseFilter.java:45)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.AbsoluteLocationFilter.doFilter(AbsoluteLocationFilter.java:65)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpResponseFilter.doFilter(HttpResponseFilter.java:45)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:85)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.secure.ForceHttpsFilter.doFilter(ForceHttpsFilter.java:74)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.ForceAuthFilter.doFilter(ForceAuthFilter.java:44)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.Filters.filter(Filters.java:67)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPoint.service(EntryPoint.java:82)
  at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPointServlet.service(EntryPointServlet.java:102)
  at oracle.dbtools.entrypoint.WebApplicationRequestEntryPoint.service(WebApplicationRequestEntryPoint.java:50)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
  at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:394)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'AJAX'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1052)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:537)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:610)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:249)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:82)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:924)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1136)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3640)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeInternal(T4CCallableStatement.java:1318)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3752)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4242)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1079)
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.oracle$1ucp$1jdbc$1proxy$1StatementProxy$2oracle$1jdbc$1internal$1OracleCallableStatement$$$Proxy.execute(Unknown Source)
  at oracle.dbtools.apex.OWA.execute(OWA.java:184)
  ... 75 more
Caused by: Error : 6550, Position : 8, Sql = begin 
 wwv_flow.ajax;
commit;
  end;, OriginalSql = begin 
 wwv_flow.ajax;
commit;
  end;, Error Msg = ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'AJAX'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
  ... 91 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First oracle apex 19.1 release had a bug, **Oracle APEX Release 19.1.0.00.15** now it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For now, use direct tomcat "localhost:8080/ords" for builder and you can use apache for run your application ... works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the order you upgraded ORDS and APEX.

If you just upgraded APEX to 19.1 then you need to run the ords **java -jar ords.war validate** so that ORDS 18.4 can fix it's installation after the APEX install. (which breaks ORDS)

Regards

Comment: It was not the case, it look like the first installation media was the wrong one. Oracle made a re up and after "Oracle APEX Release 19.1.0.00.15"